# Insertar varios registros en un solo campo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una aplicación web que me sirve para generar órdenes de producción para un taller de calzados.

Tengo estas tablas:

ORDENES_DETALLES
- ODET_id(PK)
- ODET_producto
- ODET_material
- ODET_suela
- ODET_color
- ODET_precio
- TALL_id(FK)

TALLAS
- TALL_id(PK)
- TALL_tallas

El formulario tiene 1 input por cada talla: 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 y quiero guardarlos en un solo campo(TALL_tallas). Para no crear un campo para cada talla en la tabla TALLAS.

Ejemplo: El registro guardado seria.
TALL_tallas
35,36,37,38,39

Deseo también saber como puedo usarlas por separado al momento de imprimir o mostrar los detalles de toda la orden.

Actualmente tengo la tabla de esta forma:
TALLAS
- TALL_id(PK)
- TALL_talla35
- TALL_talla36
- TALL_talla37
- TALL_talla38
- TALL_talla39

Y cada campo lo lleno con la cantidad de calzados para esa talla. Ejemplo:

TALLAS
- TALL_id(PK)
101
- TALL_talla35
1
- TALL_talla36
2
- TALL_talla37
1
- TALL_talla38
3
- TALL_talla39
1

Espero su grande ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Saludos checa [ask], no termina de quedar clara tu pregunta, anexo serviría que agregues lo que llevas hecho y dudas puntuales.

Comment: Para qué una tabla tallas si vas a denormalizar todo guardando un solo registro. Eso no te sirve para armar una fk en la orden. Por qué quieres guardar eso así (mal)?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pides se podría hacer con un campo JSON o, como te dijeron, concatenando los valores. Sin embargo el caso de uso de un JSON representa documentos anidados, y lo que tú quieres representar es un caso que se resuelve con tercera forma normal (3NF).

Hoy tienes una sábana:

```
id_orden | talla_1 | talla_2 | talla_3 | talla_4 | talla_5
----------------------------------------------------------
    1    |   5     |    9    |    2    |    12   |   4
    2    |   8     |    0    |    6    |     1   |   9
```

Y la sábana está bien para sacar reportes, pero no para operar.

Tus órdenes son una entidad que no sólo se relaciona con productos. También se relaciona con el vendedor que la realizó, con el cliente para efectos del CRM, etc.

Tus productos también son una entidad que se relacionan con otras. Por ejemplo tienen categoría y marca.

Cuando entregas la boleta o factura al cliente los datos dicen:

```
Factura 1
Detalle:
Talla 1    5 unidades  $500
Talla 2    9 unidades  $45
Talla 3    2 unidades  $120
Talla 4   12 unidades  $600
Talla 5    4 unidades  $400
```

Lo lógico sería entonces que tu modelo de datos representara algo parecido. Con una estructura al estilo

```
id_orden | id_talla | cantidad
------------------------------------
    1    |    1      |    5    
    1    |    2      |    9    
    1    |    3      |    2    
    1    |    4      |   12    
    1    |    5      |    4    
    2    |    1      |    8    
    2    |    2      |    0  
    2    |    3      |    6  
    2    |    4      |    1  
    2    |    5      |    9
```

No necesitas saber cuántas tallas existen, ni modificar la tabla en el tiempo. Esta estructura es transparente a la hora de sumar agrupando por el ID de la orden a la hora de generar la factura, y a la hora de sacar reportes tienes la orden y el producto (o talla) con lo cual puedes añadirle precio, hora, vendedor, cliente, etc.

Lo importante es usar la BBDD para lo que es buena. No le metas lógica de negocio a la base. Eso se maneja en el software y con eso mantienes separación de responsabilidades y usas cada herramienta para lo que es.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías realizar es lo siguiente:

**Primera manera (rápida):**
Agregar las tallas solicitadas en un campo, y la cantidad en otro, respetando el orden correspondiente, separados por comas o algún identificador para después hacer `.split` en la programación, quedando de la siguiente manera:

campo de tallas: '34,35,36,37,38'
campo de cantidades: '2,3,6,6,4'

Posteriormente, al obtener los registros, puedes hacer un `.split` de estas variables String, para obtener dos arrays, en donde los Index, corresponderán a la cantidad de pedidos de las tallas especificadas.

**Segunda manera (correcta):**
Tuvieras que crear una tabla de en plan "Detalle_Talla", en donde relaciones el detalle, y también la talla, y tendrías un campo más llamado "cantidad", así ya estaría normalizado. Posteriormente en las consultas tuvieras que utilizar [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) para obtener el mismo comportamiento posterior explicado en la primera manera.

Answer (score -1):

Buenas no soy un experto, pero creo que para poder insertar como deseas, osea en un solo campo debes concatenar, usando la funcion concat().

Comment: Interesante, pero después de haber ingresado las tallas concatenadas necesito también poder usarlas por separado. Ejemplo: Deseo mostrar los registros en diferentes campos. Campo 1: 35. Campo 2: 36, etc. ¿Cómo lo lograría?

Comment: En ese caso puedes intentar utilizando la funcion  SUBSTRING_INDEX(), la cual retorna la subcadena de la cadena, teniendo en cuenta su delimitador, en otras palabras, si el count es positivo, todo a la izquierda del delimitador se retorna, caso contrario si es negativo, como por ejemplo: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('35.36.37',','1);  esta devolveria 35